# save to sql server database from client side

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have a gridview with dropdownlist in it. When the user changes the item in the dropdownlist I want to save the new item in the database. I want this to happen using javascript and ajax like effect.

I know how to access the dropdownlist inside gridview using javascript and I can get the new selectd item.

How can I save it to database without server side code? I know one way of doing this is using web services. I just want to know if there is/are any other ways to do it.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just from a design/practices perspective this isn't even something you should want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way for client side script to interact with DB. If you are using ASP .Net there are only three ways you can achieve this:

using a .aspx page

using a .ashx (http handler) or

using a .asmx (web service)

The way you can achieve an AJAX call is to use [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/ajax.shtml) object.

HTH